# Употребление глагола "переживать"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно  употреблять глагол *переживать*: за кого, из-за кого или о ком?

Comment: Или — что-то. Переживают поражение, «переживают, что съели Кука».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хорошо бы контекст иметь. Вообще это глагол очень многозначный.
Вы имеете в виду "переживать" - терпеть, испытывать душевную тревогу?
Правда, и в этом случае возможны разные предлоги - и несколько разный смысл.

Переживать за кого - это желать удачи или сострадать в несчастье.
Переживать из-за кого - это больше о себе, по причине того, что "кто-то" доставил неприятность.
Переживать о ком-то - просторечный вариант "думать о ком-то".

Наверное, это не всё...

Comment: "Бабушка очень переживала за внука" - правильное управление или нет? В тех справочниках, что у меня под рукой - непонятно прописаны стилевые ограничения. У нас только так и говорят(до сегодняшнего дня у меня и сомнений не возникало), но, судя по некоторым источникам, это просторечный вариант. Вообще употребление глагола "переживать" в значении "беспокоиться" дается как ненормативное. Зная Вашу эрудицию, рассчитываю на помощь.

Comment: Ну тут не эрудит нужен, а специалист. Но на своём дилетантском уровне понимания, я согласен с тем, что "переживать - беспокоиться" - вариант если не ненормативный, то разговорный. Вариант "переживать за внука" того же уровня нормативности, что и любое другое употребление "переживать" в этом значении. Вот "переживать о ком" - и тем более "переживать за кем" мне кажутся совсем уж просторечными, до грубости.

Comment: Спасибо. Значит, в таком случае, ошибка это не синтаксическая, а речевая.

Answer (score 0):

Слово "переживать" в значении "волноваться", "тревожиться", "беспокоиться" имеет разговорную окраску и принято в условиях непринужденного общения. В книжных, официальных текстах его употреблять не следует. К тому же в указанном значении оно является непереходным, однако под влиянием синонимов нередко употребляется в сочетании с винительным падежом ("Мы за тебя переживаем"). Такое употребление уместно лишь в разговорном стиле.